# Django form warning messages

Tags: django, forms, templates

My Django form asks for a specific number (1345 in this case). Yet if the user types in some other number a warning message appears indicating the upper/lower bound of the allowed integer. How do I prevent these specific warning messages? The response to a false input should always be: "Wrong." What is the easiest way to achieve this behavious?

```
#models.py
class Player():
    code = models.PositiveIntegerField(min=1345,max=1345)
    #etc

#template.html
    {% formfield player.code with label="What is the code?" %}
```

Comment: Post the code o your form.

Answer (score 2):

You can display `error_messages`

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class PlayerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = "__all__"

        error_messages = {
            'code': {
                'max_value': _("You have to enter below the 1345."),
                'min_value': _("You have to enter above the 1345."),

            }
        }
```

So now you should get the idea. Just put text whatever you wish.